# What exactly is a register?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, flipflop, register

Sometimes I'll look at registers in asm or when debugging a C output. What exactly is a register? In my understanding, it seems like it would consist of, for example 16 D-type flip-flops connected to the same clock signal (for a 16 bit reigster). But then other times it will be referred to as something like an "8 bit latch" and not a series of flip flops.

What then would be an example of a register? And is it any different than some flip-flops of a predetermined width connected to the same clock signal?

Comment: it is easier to say `8-bit latch` than `8 flip-flops clocked by same clock signal` ... `8-bit latch` also describes the functionality

Comment: An 8 bit latch *is* a series of flip flops.

Comment: @Hearth is it about level/edge triggering again? An 8 bit latch is a register with level sensitive, whereas an 8 bit flip flop is a register with edge sensitive.

Comment: @Hearth, i think that the OP may be saying `and not referred to as a series of flip flops` .... David542, please clarify the wording because it is vague

Comment: The word 'register' is overloaded, it has different meaning in different contexts.

Comment: @jsotola well, I really don't know what it is -- whether it even **is** a D-type flip flop or is something else, so basically just an understanding of how a register might be implemented with the components.

Comment: @David542 does it even matter? ... all you need to know is how to write data to the register and how to read data from the register .... it is really just a black box with a data path and control signals ... it is something like a class object in programming ... you have public functions and public variables for your use, and you do not worry about the internal workings

Comment: look at figure 10-2 on page 68 of this http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: it varies by architecture and implementation.it could be individual flip-flops/latch per register or it could be a small sram (register file), in rare occasions you may find an isa where the registers can be addressed in memory space with an address, but that doesnt mean that they are using a register file necessarily as you can implement that with individual flip-flops. at the end of the day though,the underlying implementation needs to match the ISA so up to the designers as to how to do that, and no reason to assume one version of the same isa is built the same way from one chip to the next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of assembly language programming, a "register" is a primitive object in the ISA (instruction set architecture), which is what defines the interface between software and hardware. A register stores a single value, and the number of bits determines how many distinct values it can hold: N bits can hold 2<sup>N</sup> values.

Some instructions will allow you to set or modify the value stored in a register, either directly or through side-effects. Other instructions will use the value stored in the register as either data or addresses. All of this is defined in the instruction descriptions, also part of the ISA.

As a programmer, that's all you "need to know" — the ISA is specifically intended to hide the physical implementation details. The underlying hardware implementation could use any of a number of different circuit techniques (and many have been used over the years), but thinking of a register as a bank of flip-flops or latches (these two terms are equivalent at this level) is a useful mental model.

Comment: thanks for this comprehensive answer. Out of curiosity, what are the most common implementations that are used today? Or does it still widely differ across the board

Comment: I don't have direct knowledge, but I would assume that the CMOS D flip-flop would be the most common implementation in modern CPUs.